# Error while implementing List ADT "member reference base type 'MOVE' (aka 'struct s_move *')is not a structure or union"

Tags: c, linked-list, abstract-data-type

I am trying to implement a List ADT in C, but I couldn't find much help on the intenet since it seems like very example is in C++ which I don't know anything about. I can completely understand the data stucture (at least, I think I understood) but I have trouble making it an ADT, separating files and so on.
When trying to implement the append function, in the cycle that traverses the list I get an error like:
`member reference base type 'MOVE' (aka 'struct s_move *')is not a structure or union` 
I understand that the problem is with pointers and by simplifying a bit my data, since this is clearly ovekill for the problem I'm solving, I'd like to make it work this way for learning purposes.

move.h

```
// This is the node of the list
#ifndef MOVE_H
#define MOVE_H

typedef struct s_move *MOVE;

/* Initializes a new move */
MOVE move_init(int i, int j);

#endif
```

move.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "move.h"

struct s_move {
    int i;
    int j;
    MOVE *next;
};

MOVE move_init(int i, int j) {
  MOVE m;
  m->i = i;
  m->j = j;
  m->next = NULL;
  return m;
}
```

moves.h

```
#ifndef MOVES_H
#define MOVES_H

#include "move.h"

typedef struct s_moves *MOVES;

/* Initializes the list of moves */
MOVES moves_init();

/* Appends a new move at the end of the list */
void moves_append(MOVES moves, MOVE move);

#endif
```

moves.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "moves.h"
#include "move.h"

struct s_moves {
  MOVE *head;
};

MOVES moves_init() {
  MOVES m;

  m->head = (MOVE *)malloc(sizeof(MOVE));
  m->head = NULL;
  return m;
}

void moves_append(MOVES moves, MOVE move) {
  MOVE *ptr;
  //***********************************
  //HERE I GET THE ERROR ON ptr->next
  //***********************************
  for(ptr = moves->head; ptr->next != NULL; ptr = ptr->next) {
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

Which is the right way to do this? Sorry if I'm repeating myself, I'd like to use ADT without simplifying the structure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is that the variable`ptr` is of the type of `MOVE *` which when expanded becomes `struct s_move **`. That is, the variable `ptr` is a pointer to a pointer to an object of type `struct s_move` or we can say that the variable `ptr` doesn't store any structure or union and instead it stores a pointer. Hence, the error you are getting.

What I suggest you do is replace the typedefs you have written with the following :

```
typedef struct s_move MOVE
```

and

```
typedef struct s_moves MOVES
```

Although, I don't know the specifics about how theses structures will actually be used but replacing your `typedefs` with the above ones should resolve the errors.